# Need advice on building small incubator

Tags: thermodynamics, heating-systems

I need to build an incubator that can vary temperature between 32 degrees and 36 degrees Celsius with discreet or continuous control. It needs to be made with perspex. It needs to be a two chamber design where the heating is happening in the lower chamber and the upper chamber is where the incubation is happening. The horizontal wall between the upper and lower chamber is to have the perforations through which hot air is to rise from lower chamber into upper chamber. The size of the upper chamber may be somewhere in the range of 180mm X 80mm X 80mm.

[image]

I need ideas on how to achieve it. What would be the heating source and how to control the temperature. We don't want the heat to be so much that it melts the perspex, but we would like the desired temperature to be achieved with a few minutes max.

Comment: visit a pet shop and have a look at heating systems for reptiles

Comment: @jsotola that's actually a good idea, if something readymade is available then that would be cool. I found heating pads but no incubators.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas for heating you can use:

1)Heating elements
2)Infrared bulbs.
3)Gas light (not my favorite choice but here for completeness)

Detecting temperature:

1)Air temperature sensor
2)Contact temperature sensor: you might find that air isnt very good at absorbing infrared as whatever you are trying to incubate.
3)Non contact temperature sensor.[Relevant link](https://www.processparameters.co.uk/comparing-contact-and-non-contact-temperature-sensors/)

Control:

1)Arduino
2)Raspberry pi ([Relevant link](https://raspberrypi-guide.github.io/electronics/temperature-monitoring))

Comment: What kind of heating element? I don't want to melt my perspex. And any simpler technology than arduino possible? I don't want to use infrared bulbs, there is going to be a small animal within the incubator, don't want to burn him, just want to warm the air around the animal.

Comment: Perspex melts at 160C. Have a look at this air heater for the animal then. https://www.amazon.com/Constant-Temperature-Heating-Element-Incubator/dp/B07K26YQCG/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=incubator+heating+element&qid=1702119637&sr=8-6

Comment: Wow thanks, something like this might just work, but its too expensive. In my geography its as much as 50USD, but I'll look for cheaper options

Comment: If I just put a hundred watt bulb in the bottom chamber, and control it with arduino, would it generate enough heat to heat the above chamber by natural flow of hot air above?

Comment: If a bulb is switched on and off by arduino, is its element expected to go bad sooner?

Comment: I'd like a solution which can effectively heat both in winters and summers

Comment: This is a healthy conversation to come up with a solution, have you heard of a pugh matrix to weigh the pros and cons? I'll try to do abit more research and get back to you a solution.

Comment: Have you come across these lamps before? https://www.amazon.com/HealSmart-Reptile-Heat-2-Pack-Ceramic/dp/B0C2CK11RY/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=heat%2Blamp%2Bbulbs%2Bfor%2Bfood&qid=1702135559&sr=8-1-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1